# How to return variable from within an if statement for use in a separate method?

Tags: java, swing, methods, actionlistener

```
public int randomNumber()
{
    return (int) (Math.random() * (11 - 1) + 1);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource() == question)
    {
        int one = randomNumber();
        int two = randomNumber();
        int three = randomNumber();
        int four = randomNumber();          
        label.setText("Is " + one + "+" + two + " greater than, less than or equal to " + three + "+" + four + "?");
    }

    if(e.getSource() == lessThan)
    {
            if((one+two)<(three+four))
                    label.setText("Correct!");
    }
}
```

In this code, how do I keep the randomly generated variables: `one`, `two`, `three` and `four`.

I am displaying those variables for the question the user is asked. I then want to be able to compare these variables to check for the correct user input answer and display appropriate feedback.

Currently, when I compile this code, it gives an error saying that the variables `one`, `two`, `three` and `four` cannot be found, which makes sense since they are within a seperate statement. How do I make them reusable within the `actionPerformed` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare variables `one, two, three,` and `four` at a higher scope that is visible to the actionPerformed method you have. So for example, they could be instance variables in the class that `randomNumber()` and `actionPerformed()` make up. That way the variables maintain state between method calls, and are visible through `actionPerformed`.

After that, you can store the result of verifying if the user answered correctly by storing that answer in an instance variable as well (if you need to use it elsewhere).

Comment: I added the variables at the top of my program and set them to be a random number when the question button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Your setting of int one, two, three.... should be before your if statement. Your variables are only defined if you enter the if statement, if you don't enter it then they are never defined.

```
if(e.getSource() == question)
    {
        int one = randomNumber();
        int two = randomNumber();
        int three = randomNumber();
        int four = randomNumber();          
        label.setText("Is " + one + "+" + two + " greater than, less than or equal to " + three + "+" + four + "?");
    }
```

should be

```
 int one = randomNumber();
 int two = randomNumber();
 int three = randomNumber();
 int four = randomNumber();
 if(e.getSource() == question)
        {          
            label.setText("Is " + one + "+" + two + " greater than, less than or equal to " + three + "+" + four + "?");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class a{
    private int one,two,three,four;
    public int getOne(){
        return this.one;
    }

public void setOne(int one){
this.one = one;
}
    public int randomNumber()
    {
        return (int) (Math.random() * (11 - 1) + 1);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        if(e.getSource() == question)
        {
            setOne(randomNumber());
            two = randomNumber();
            three = randomNumber();
            four = randomNumber();          
            label.setText("Is " + one + "+" + two + " greater than, less than or equal to " + three + "+" + four + "?");
        }

        if(e.getSource() == lessThan)
        {
                if((getOne()+two)<(three+four))
                        label.setText("Correct!");
        }
    }
}
}
```